# How can I lower mouse speed?

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, xfce

I'm using xUbuntu 16.10 on XFCE.

I'm not satisfied with the minimum value in the setting. I tried editing xorg.conf but than the system won't boot.

I modified the xorg config file like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier      "Logitech"                    # Whatever you want.
   MatchProduct    "Logitech optical mouse"   # Product name from xinput list.
   Option          "ConstantDeceleration" "3" # The same value as xinput.
EndSection
```

And at startup i was getting black screen so i restored the config file.

I also tried

> xinput --set-prop 11 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 3

Where 11 it's my mouse ID. Even with sudo. I don't notice any variations even if I put 8 in there. (Should it be immediate?) By the way nothing's change even logging out and logging in.

Any other method?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting the new question, but you need to explain what you've done. Show the edits you made to xorg.conf, explain what happened. Have you tried any of the solutions mentioned in the questions linked to in the "Related" section on the right? Did they work? If not, how did they fail?

Comment: It would also be a good idea to state what UI framework you're using so the people can suggest an appropriate tool.

Comment: Are you using Unity desktop?

Comment: I'm using XFCE.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum value disables mouse acceleration and leaves you with your mouse's dpi. To lower the mouse speed you have to slide the slider a bit to the right, just to make in non-minimum or if you can configure your mouse's dpi, you can do that, only some mice allow that and they often do it with on board buttons.

Comment: I can't change my mouse DPI